# How to run different code for different SDK levels without errors in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

Inside a method I run a line which is different for different SDKs. And the lint marker always marks it as an error and suggests me to add a new api annotation for the whole method, but this is only one line of code I think it's pointless to create a new method just for this.
I have this in many places, but for example :

```
private void methodA(){

  ... 
  some code (that is good for both) 
  ... 

  if(Build.VERSION>SDK_INT >= 16)
    pb.setBackground(anim);
  else
    pb.setBackgroundDrawable(anim);

  ...
  more code
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking:
>
> Change **NewApi** Severity to **Ignore**.

[image]

Comment: I do want eclipse to warn me about SDK level issues, can I make it to mark it a a warning and not as an error?

Comment: Thanks, I've found out, just changed instead of ignore to warning

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you have to use an annotation or disable the inspection completely.

If you used the new [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), however, you wouldn't have this problem. It will understand that the code under the `if` block will run only if the API level is >= 16, and will check the methods accordingly.